# What happens if I don't set Site bindings in IIS 7

Tags: architecture, iis-7, windows-server-2008, 3-tier

I would like to know if the application will not be accessible of I don't set Site bindings on IIS 7 ( which is my web server)

I have the IP of my web server set at the Load balancer end so that the end user requests hitting the load balancer would be directed to the web server.

In this case, is it mandatory to set the Site bindings? If I don't set it, will I not be able to access my application?

Please let me know if you need any further info to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a site through the GUI you have to select something for the binding.

Even if you do it command line like:

```
appcmd add site /name: string /id: uint /physicalPath: string /bindings: string
```

Without the bindings specified the site won't start in IIS